# Why does my cat make strong eye contact?

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat is 15 years old and is not aggressive (she's very coward) but she often makes strong eye contact with everyone.

The most common case is when she has just eaten, I look at her, she stops, sits on her back paws and look into my eyes for dozens of seconds (even few minutes sometimes), silently (while she usually talks a lot). What does it mean?

I thought that when a cat had such a behavior it was a kind of signe of defiance or threat, but she looks relaxed, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10061/why-does-my-cat-bite-my-face-while-being-affectionate/

Comment: my cat do this too and it feels a little uncomfortable and she continues staring even if i look away.my cat is the kindest  cat in the world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If she seems relaxed then it's probably nothing more than her just watching you.. both of my two do this at points.

Try returning the eye contact and give her some slow blinks and see if she returns them, if she does then that's a strong sign of trust.